# Extending a Real Function $u$ to a Holomorphic Function: Must $f(\mathbb{R})= u(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

We are supposed to decide whether a set of real functions $u_n(x+iy)$ can be extended to complex differentiable functions on $\mathbb{C}$ and give the extension.

My approach was to use the Cauchy-Riemann Equations and then integrate to find a real-valued $v_n$ such that $f=u_n(x+iy)+iv(x+iy)$ satisfies C-R.

My understanding of what "extending" means is a bit shaky. The function $f$ found using this method is by design holomorphic as long as $u$ and $v$ are differentiable. But in one example $f(1)=3+i\neq3=u(1)$

Is this still correct, even if $f(\mathbb{R})\neq u(\mathbb{R})$? Did I "extend" u properly or is this a fatal error?

Comment: You wrote $u_n(x+iy)$. What is the domain of $x$ and $y$? If they admit arbitrary values, then $u_n$ is a real function of complex variable. It is already define on all complex numbers. Is it only defined $u_n(x)$ for all $x$, and $y=0$?

Comment: An extension of a function $u:A\subset B\to C$, defined on $A$, to the set $C$ is a function $f: C\to B$ such that $u=f|_A$. They must agree on the domain of $u$.

Comment: The use of Cauchy-Riemann that you seem to be doing doesn't give an extension of a real function, but it compute a harmonic conjugate function $v$ and an analytic function $f$ of which $u$ is the real part.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thanks, the $u_n$ are defined $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, this is exactly what confuses me. How would you *extend* a function $u$?

Comment: @conditionalMethod In your second comment do you mean $f:C\rightarrow B$ or $f:B \rightarrow C$?

Comment: $f:B\to C$, yes. If the $u$ are already defined on $\mathbb{C}$, then to which larger set do they want them to be extended? Something is wrong in the formulation. They have to specify which is the larger set to which the functions' definition must be extended. Must likely, they are not really defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$, only on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I appreciate your help, I have asked the tutors for clarification. :)